# Select 2 is not working after appending through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

Select2 behaves differently while trying to add more select through jquery.

Initially its working fine but while trying to append on click of add button its not working correctly.

find the below code

```js
function selectRefresh(){
    $('.select2').select2({
        tags:true,
        placeholder: "Select an Option",
        allowClear: true,
        width:'100%'
    });
}
$('.add').click(function(){
    $('.main').append($('.new-wrap').html());
    selectRefresh();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    selectRefresh();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
    <select class="form-control select2">
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <select class="form-control select2">
        <option>test 1</option>
        <option>test 2</option>
        <option>test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
```

Comment: "it's not working correctly" is not helpful.  Please describe what you expect to see and what behavior you're seeing that is incorrect.  (That being said, the issue may have something to do with `$(.select2)` returning multiple objects)

Comment: what behaviour i am seeing can't you try that code i have posted....everything is mentioned properly if you really want to fix it you can try the code otherwise leave it

Comment: People reading your question are not mind readers.  They don't know if the behavior they are seeing is what you intended or not.  You need to explain what the issue is instead of just saying "It's not working correctly"

Comment: see the below answer 100% correct .those who are really interested they are trying with the code first after that if they are facing any issue then asking questions.....i have posted full code if you would have try once then u will get to know the exact issue any way thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize select2 plugin only for `select` tags within the `.main` class otherwise it will initialize for the hidden elements and there will be some additional HTML tags which are generated by the select2 plugin.

```js
function selectRefresh() {
  $('.main .select2').select2({
    //-^^^^^^^^--- update here
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Select an Option",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'
  });
}
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.main').append($('.new-wrap').html());
  selectRefresh();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectRefresh();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
  <select class="form-control select2">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <select class="form-control select2">
    <option>test 1</option>
    <option>test 2</option>
    <option>test 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If there multiple places to do the same then select those based on common ancestor or siblings.

1. Using a common parent element :

```js
function selectRefresh() {
  $('.main .select2').select2({
    //-^^^^^^^^--- update here
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Select an Option",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'
  });
}
$('.add').click(function() {
  var $prnt = $(this).parent();
  $prnt.find('.main').append($prnt.find('.new-wrap').html());
  selectRefresh();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectRefresh();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test 1</option>
      <option>test 2</option>
      <option>test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test 1</option>
      <option>test 2</option>
      <option>test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
</div>
```

2. By selecting previous sibling element :

```js
function selectRefresh() {
  $('.main .select2').select2({
    //-^^^^^^^^--- update here
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Select an Option",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'
  });
}
$('.add').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prevAll('.main').first().append($this.prevAll('.new-wrap').first().html());
  selectRefresh();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectRefresh();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
  <select class="form-control select2">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <select class="form-control select2">
    <option>test 1</option>
    <option>test 2</option>
    <option>test 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>

<div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
  <select class="form-control select2">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <select class="form-control select2">
    <option>test 1</option>
    <option>test 2</option>
    <option>test 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
```

**UPDATE 2 :** In my opinion, it's better to initialize the new element instead of reinitializing all the element at each time.

```js
function selectRefresh($sel) {
  $sel.select2({
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Select an Option",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'
  });
}
$('.add').click(function() {
  var $prnt = $(this).parent();;
  var $clone = $prnt.find('.new-wrap select').clone()
  $prnt.find('.main').append($clone);
  selectRefresh($clone);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectRefresh($('.main .select2'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test 1</option>
      <option>test 2</option>
      <option>test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="new-wrap" style="display: none;">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option>test 1</option>
      <option>test 2</option>
      <option>test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: HI thank you so much in other place i am using same but its coming twice one is working another is in disabled mode could you please help me

Comment: It's in laravel actually so i just created a new file and posted the above

Comment: i also tried that it comes with 2 select picker one is working and another is not

Comment: thanks anyway i got the solution as beacuse of messy code and call to select in different different place again it was not working now its fine